# Implement and train YOLO 3 with Opencv and C++

Tags: deep-learning, opencv

I want to implement and train YOLO 3 with my dataset using Opencv and C++. I can't find an example to start with, or a tutorial to explain how to train YOLO with my own data. All of the tutorials I found are in Python and don't use Opencv. Do you have any examples, or an explanation of how to code an object detector with YOLO 3, opencv with C++?

I find [this tutorial](https://www.learnopencv.com/deep-learning-based-human-pose-estimation-using-opencv-cpp-python/).

The code for this tutorial is [here](https://github.com/spmallick/learnopencv).

but I can't find the C++ code. I think it exists only with Python.

Comment: Try [this tutorial](https://www.learnopencv.com/deep-learning-based-object-detection-using-yolov3-with-opencv-python-c/)

Comment: Thank you, but this tutorial is only to test YOLO with an already trained dataset, me i want to train my  own YOLOv3 model with my dataset